# Rotating an image with canvas context

Tags: javascript, canvas

i have this code

```
Allocate.prototype.Rotate = function () {
var canvas = document.getElementById("underCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = canvas.width;
context.lineWidth = "1";
context.save();
context.translate(this.drawStart.x + this.img.width * 0.5,
              this.drawStart.y + this.img.height * 0.5);
context.rotate(Math.Pi/2);
context.translate(-(this.drawStart.x + this.img.width * 0.5),
              -(this.drawStart.y + this.img.height * 0.5));
context.drawImage(this.img, this.drawStart.x, this.drawStart.y, this.drawStart.w, this.drawStart.h, this.drawStart.x, this.drawStart.y, this.drawStart.w, this.drawStart.h);

context.rect(this.drawStart.x, this.drawStart.y, this.drawStart.w, this.drawStart.h);
context.stroke();
context.restore();
}
```

what i think this method of class allocate should do - is draw image `(this.img)` rotated by 90 degree inside a rectange. What comes out: it draws a transformed rectangle but image is still not rotated. Why?

Can anyone help me to accomplish this?

this code is a part of class allocate. i am doing sorta web paint, and want to be able to rotate allocated region. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to translate before rotating if you want to rotate the image by its center (adjust as needed):

```
/// first translate
context.translate(this.drawStart.x + this.img.width * 0.5,
                  this.drawStart.y + this.img.height * 0.5);

/// then rotate
context.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);  /// 90 degrees

/// then translate back
context.translate(-(this.drawStart.x + this.img.width * 0.5),
                  -(this.drawStart.y + this.img.height * 0.5));

/// draw image
```

The cause for it to not work can be several:

- Is the image loaded properly (ie. is the onload handler used to make the image is available at the time it is being drawn)
- What values do the properties contain and are they valid (ie. not undefined etc.)

For the rotation to work you need to choose a rotation point, or pivot. The pivot is usually the center of the image which is obtained by using its half width and height.

As rotate always rotate at the coordinate system's origin (0,0) you first need to translate this origin to where the center of the image would be.

Then rotate, and to draw the image properly you need to translate back after rotation or else the corner of the image would be in the center as images are always drawn from top left.

The rectangle must be drawn with the same transformation applied of course.

Comment: the image inside rect now disapears. i think its related with my drawImage-8parameter way of drawing. Trying to change it

Comment: @AlexanderCapone yeah, you need to adjust for that too. I am just showing the basic principle here :-)

Comment: i edited code in question.
can you explain why is not it working? because i just can't understand, nothing's rotating!

Comment: @AlexanderCapone certainly. Answer's updated. If you still can't get the image to rotate I suggest you set up a fiddle so we can take a closer look at the code/problem in context (no pun).

Comment: thank you, found mistake, it was sooo simple
Math.PI not Math.Pi

Comment: @AlexanderCapone Excellent. Hm, though *I* had made that typo (I discovered and corrected in my example) but now I see it's in the original post. There you go... :-)